# How to hide text marks in altair/vega bar chart when bars too short

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I'm using Altair to create a stacked bar chart with a text mark layer that shows a label just below the top of each bar:

[image]

The problem is that when the bars are small the text label doesn't fit, so they overlap and become illegible.

I can use a condition to hide the text mark but only using a threshold on the bar value:

```py
text=alt.condition(alt.datum.tickets < 100, alt.value(""), "issue:N")
```

How do I make the predicate in that condition compare the bar height in pixels with the text height in pixels? I'm sure this kind of dynamic geometrical condition must be a common scenario.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to access the bar height in pixels directly in vega-lite/altair, so you would probably need to stick with a manually set threshold as in your solution (or compute it based on that you know the overall chart height in pixels)

Comment: You could have a transform that calculates the value percentage. This way you could test if the value < 5% for example set the opacity to full or color to transparent etc